# Angular-Material dropdown not displaying correct value when same selection is made?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a input field where the user can both type and select from a dropdown. I have three dropdowns [Test1, Test2, Test3]. Whenever I change the dropdown from Test1 to Test2 or Test3, the display is populated without issue. However, when I 'change' the dropdown by selecting Test1 from Test1 (essentially, selecting the same dropdown as the current selected option) - my html displays [object object]

In my .ts file, I made a function:

```
  stringify() {
    let json = JSON.stringify(this.brand.Car);
    json = json.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
    console.log(json);
    return json;
  }
```

and replaced from [ngModel]="brand.Car" to [ngModel]="stringify()" to see if I was passing in something other than a string when the same selection was made but the behavior is the same - the string is displayed successfully when a different selection is made but [object Object] is displayed when the same selection is made.

```
<mat-input-container fxFlex="18" fxFlexOffset="1">
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Some placeholder"
      [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete"
      [ngModel]="brand?.Car"
      (ngModelChange)="filter($event)"
      [disabled]="disabled"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" 
(optionSelected)="optionSelected($event)" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of country" [value]="state">
        <span>{{ state?.Car }}</span>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-input-container>
```

Comment: you're put in mat-option [value]="state", so is an object, put [value]="state.Car" (or the propertie you want to get in the input)